# where is the dynamic library file(.so) for sharedmem.h of Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, nnapi

I am trying to build NNAPI c++ native program, and I need to use sharedmem library.
I found dynamic library file for NeuralNetwork.h however I cannot find dynamic library file for sharedmem.h. Thus I have a linker error such as,

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: ASharedMemory_create
>>> referenced by simple_model.cc
>>>               CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/simple_model.cc.o:(SimpleModel::SimpleModel(unsigned long, int, int, unsigned long))
>>> referenced by simple_model.cc
>>>               CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/simple_model.cc.o:(SimpleModel::SimpleModel(unsigned long, int, int, unsigned long))
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

how can i link for sharedmem.h file.

Answer (score 1):

add android.so in your CMakeLists.txt as below.

```
find_library(
    android-lib
    android)
```

and add the library to your target.

```
target_link_libraries(
    jnitest
    ${log-lib} ${android-lib})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better way, but searching for the function name with the filter `file:.*\.map\.txt` will find the library it's defined in: https://cs.android.com/search?q=ASharedMemory_create%20file:.*%5C.map%5C.txt&ssfr=1

In this case it's libandroid.